# How to query across three tables joined by an intermediate table?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I just have one probably really dumb problem but I can't solve this.

I currently have 3 tables:

```
PROJECT    
PROJECT_CATEGORY     
CATEGORY
```

Now `PROJECT_CATEGORY` is an intermediate table so it contains only primary key from `PROJECT` and `CATEGORY` like `pID` and `cID`.

I know how I can write a query if I have a `pID` in table `CATEGORY` but in this case I only have intermediate table. So how I can create a query that will check these 3 tables and then it will show me all categories and which projects they're assigned to?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
select c.*, p.* 
from categories c
inner join PROJECT_CATEGORY pc on pc.category_id = c.id
inner join projects p on pc.project_id = p.id
```

Comment: there is a `c` missing: `from categories c`

Comment: Thanks, i forgot thath i can use more then once INNER JOIN ^^

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want to find whether a category has a project or not. Following query shows how many projects are associated with a given category.

If you want the list of all projects associated with all categories, you can use the second query. *Category 4* will not be displayed in the second result because of `INNER JOIN`, since there are no projects associated with this category. If you want Category 4 to show up, you have to change `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

[**Click here to view the demo in SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/52794/24)

*Script*:

```
CREATE TABLE project 
(
  projectid INT NOT NULL 
  , projectname VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE projectcategory
(
    projectid   INT NOT NULL 
  , categoryid  INT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE category
(
    categoryid      INT NOT NULL
  , categoryname    VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO project (projectid, projectname) VALUES 
    (1, 'project 1'),
    (2, 'project 2'),
    (3, 'project 3');

INSERT INTO category (categoryid, categoryname) VALUES 
    (1, 'category 1'),
    (2, 'category 2'),
    (3, 'category 3'),
    (4, 'category 4');

INSERT INTO projectcategory (projectid, categoryid) VALUES 
    (1, 1),
    (3, 2),
    (2, 1),
    (2, 2),
    (2, 3),
    (2, 2);

SELECT          c.categoryid
            ,   c.categoryname
            ,   COUNT(pc.categoryid) Number_Of_Projects
FROM            category c 
left outer join projectcategory pc 
on              pc.categoryid = c.categoryid
GROUP BY        c.categoryid
ORDER BY        c.categoryname;

SELECT          c.categoryid
            ,   c.categoryname
            ,   p.projectid
            ,   p.projectname
FROM            category c 
inner join      projectcategory pc 
on              pc.categoryid = c.categoryid
inner join      project p
on              p.projectid = pc.projectid
ORDER BY        c.categoryname;
```

*Output*:

```
CATEGORYID CATEGORYNAME NUMBER_OF_PROJECTS
---------- ------------ ------------------
1          category 1           2
2          category 2           3
3          category 3           1
4          category 4           0

CATEGORYID CATEGORYNAME PROJECTID PROJECTNAME
---------- ------------ --------- -----------
1          category 1       1      project 1
1          category 1       2      project 2
2          category 2       3      project 3
2          category 2       2      project 2
2          category 2       2      project 2
3          category 3       2      project 2
```